# Kubernetes access hardware (device plugin?)

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have an Edge device running a Kubernetes cluster. I have some things that need to be configured on the hardware device, such as:

- Network configuration (e.g. configure IP address).
- Time (e.g. ptp1588).
- There are some LEDs on the hardware that I want to control.
- R/W data from a connected USB

For such purposes, a Docker container running on Kubernetes is not the way to go -> is it? I read something about privileged docker mode, but I can imagine that this doesn't seem to be a good way from a security point of view.

Are Kubernetes device plugins the right way in this case?
Or should these services be "native" services running alongside the Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`privileged` containers are the easiest way to go, to it is not recommended in production. Linux capabilities provide a more [fine-grained solution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-capabilities-for-a-container) It allows to 'pick' only required features from `privileged` mode.

For more details about Privileged Containers see [these docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#privileged):

> **Privileged** - determines if any container in a pod can enable privileged mode. By default a container is not allowed to access any
> devices on the host, but a "privileged" container is given access to
> all devices on the host. This allows the container nearly all the same
> access as processes running on the host. This is useful for containers
> that want to use linux capabilities like manipulating the network
> stack and accessing devices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you would say: Create a docker container "network interface configuration service" give this container the specific capabilities to be able to configure the network interface.?

Comment: I would create a privileged pod via k8s: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#privileged-mode-for-containers. You can use `nodeSelector` directive to launch the pod a a selected node, or you can use a `daemonSet` to launch the pod on all nodes if you can to configure hardware an all node. You can also mix both of them to launch the pods on a given set of nodes: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#running-pods-on-select-nodes